# Knockout JS passing parameter to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, durandal

I'm working on Durandal project and i need to know the best way to call a function passing parameters from the HTML side.
In the previous versions I used always the way:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: rows">
 <div data-bind="visible: $root.myFunction.bind($data,'parameter')">
  ...
  ...
 </div>
</div>
```

But in this case in the Js side, in my function i receive only the main objects: I can't receive my ROW data and I can't receive the 'parameter' value!
This is my model in the js side:

```
define(['services/datacontext', 'durandal/app', 'config'], 
 function (datacontext, app, config) {
   var model = function () {
      var self = this;
      ...
      ...
      ...
   }

   model.prototype.myFunction(parameter) {
      var show = false;
      ...
      ...
      return show;
   }

   return model;
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can access your `$data` as `this` within your `myFunction` - the first parameter to `.bind` sets the context (context = the object that `this` refers to).

```
   model.prototype.myFunction(parameter) {
      var show = false;
      // `this` is the $data you specified in your view
      return show;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a funciton expression:

```
<!-- function expression -->
<div data-bind="click: function (data) { myFunction('param1', data) }">...</div>
```

this way you avoid passing only one parameter.

Example:

```
<p>Test</p>
<div data-bind="foreach: test">
    <button data-bind="click: function (data) { myFunction('param1', data) }">Test</button>
</div>

ko.applyBindings({
    test: [{
        myFunction: function (param1, data) {
            alert(param1 + " " + data.data);
            debugger;
        },
        data: "test1"
    }, {
        myFunction: function (param1, data) {
            alert(param1 + " " + data.data);
        },
        data: "test2"
    }]
});
```

[Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/9AZjN/](http://jsfiddle.net/9AZjN/)

Comment: Thank you for answer, used in the "click" binding it's ok, but in visible binding i receive the equal of $data in "param1" parameter and UNDEFINED in "data" parameter.